# Need help to deserialize json with Jackson from Spring-boot

Tags: java, json, post, jackson, spring-boot

I'm trying to POST a Json to my REST service, but I'm getting error with charset, I did a very simple example that reproduces my error.

Simple model Person

```
public class Person {

    public Person() {}

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Simple rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"/person"}, method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> newPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {     
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(person.getName(), HttpStatus.OK);     
    }

}
```

When I POST json:

```
{
    "name":"Joao"
}
```

works fine, I got a 200 OK and "Joao" on my response body.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4
Date: Mon, 25 May 2015 19:09:56 GMT

Joao
```

but if I try a json with a LATIN character like

```
{
    "name":"João"
}
```

I got the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 25 May 2015 19:12:56 GMT
Connection: close

{"timestamp":1432581176997,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read JSON: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x6f\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@10b0d4cd; line: 2, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.example.model.Person[\"name\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x6f\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@10b0d4cd; line: 2, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.example.model.Person[\"name\"])","path":"/person"}
```

I'm using spring-boot 1.2.3.RELEASE and it has jackson 2.5.1 as dependency.

I could not find a solution to this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: **How** do you post the JSON? Do you read it from a file? If so, what is the encoding of the file, and how do you read it? Show us the code. Also, the point of RestController is that all methods are implicitely annotated with ResponseBody. You don't need that annotation.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm using SoapUI 5.1.3 to post my JSON.

Comment: Well SoapUI must not encode its JSON in UTF8 correctly. Or you make it use a file which is not UTF8-encoded.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try to use another way to post my Json

Comment: @JBNizet You were right, the problem was with SOAP UI, thank you for your advice, I was hours trying to solve that problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved there was a bug with SOAP UI